# How do I need to use Euler-Maclaurin summation formula to calcuate the limits $\lim S_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion, limsup-and-liminf, conditional-convergence

Dear Sirs and Dear Madams,

I need to calculate the limit of $$S_{n} = \sum\limits_{k =1}^{n} [ \dfrac{1}{4k-3} + \dfrac{1}{4k - 1} - \dfrac{1}{2k} ] .$$

I show that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty } S_{n} &=&  \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} \left[   \dfrac{1}{4k-3} - \dfrac{1}{4k-2} +  \dfrac{1}{4k-1} - \dfrac{1}{4k}  + \dfrac{1}{2} \left[  \dfrac{1}{2k-1} -\dfrac{1}{2k} \right]      \right] \\
&=& \dfrac{3}{2} \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}  \left[  \dfrac{1}{2k-1} -\dfrac{1}{2k} \right] \\
&=&  \dfrac{3}{2} \ln 2.
\end{eqnarray*}

However, I tried to do that by using "Euler-Maclaurin summation formula" as follows:

1. We have $ S_{n} =  \sum\limits_{k =1}^{n} (\dfrac{1}{4k-3} + \dfrac{1}{4k-1} - \dfrac{1}{2k})$.

Put 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) = \dfrac{1}{4x-3} + \dfrac{1}{4x-1} - \dfrac{1}{2x}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
f^{(k)} (x) = \dfrac{(-4)^k k!}{(4x-3)^{k+1}} + \dfrac{(-4)^k k!}{(4x-1)^{k+1}} - \dfrac{(-1)^k k!}{2(x)^{k+1}}
\end{eqnarray}
2. Using Euler's formula, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
S_{n} &=&  \int\limits_1^n f(x) dx + \sum\limits_{k=1}^m (-1)^k \dfrac{B_k}{k!} \left\lbrace f^{(k-1)}(N) - f^{k-1}(1)  \right\rbrace   + \dfrac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m!} \int\limits_1^{N} \overline{B_m}(x) f^{(m)} (x) dx. 
\end{eqnarray}
Choose $m = 1$ and note that $\overline{B_1}(x) = x - [x] - \dfrac{1}{2}$, we have
 \begin{eqnarray}
S_{n} &=&  \int\limits_1^n f(x) dx - \dfrac{B_1}{1!} \left\lbrace f(n) - f(1)  \right\rbrace   + \dfrac{1}{1!} \int\limits_1^{n} \overline{B_1}(x) f^{'} (x) dx.\\
&=& \int\limits_1^n f(x) dx - \dfrac{B_1}{1!} \left\lbrace f(n) - f(1)  \right\rbrace   + \dfrac{1}{1!} \int\limits_1^{n} (x - [x] - \dfrac{1}{2}) f^{'} (x) dx.\\
&=& \int\limits_1^n f(x) dx + \dfrac{1}{2} \left\lbrace f(n) - f(1)  \right\rbrace   + \int\limits_1^{n} x f^{'} (x) dx -  \dfrac{1}{2} \int\limits_1^{n}  f^{'} (x) dx -   \int\limits_1^{n}  [x]  f^{'} (x) dx.\\
&=& \int\limits_1^n f(x) dx  + \int\limits_1^{n} x f^{'} (x) dx -   \int\limits_1^{n}  [x]  f^{'} (x) dx.\\
&=& \int\limits_1^n f(x) dx  + nf(n) - f(1) - \int\limits_1^{n}  f (x) dx -   \int\limits_1^{n}  [x]  f^{'} (x) dx.\\
&=&  nf(n) - f(1)  -   \int\limits_1^{n}  [x]  f^{'} (x) dx.\\
&=& \dfrac{n}{4n-3} + \dfrac{n}{4n-1} - \dfrac{1}{2} - 1 - \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{2} - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k \int\limits_k^{k+1}  f^{'} (x) dx.\\
&=& \dfrac{n}{4n-3} + \dfrac{n}{4n-1} - \dfrac{4}{3} -  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k (f(k+1) - f(k))\\
&=& \dfrac{n}{4n-3} + \dfrac{n}{4n-1} - \dfrac{4}{3} -  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \{ \dfrac{k}{4k+1} + \dfrac{k}{4k+3} - \dfrac{k}{2k+2} - \dfrac{k}{4k-3} - \dfrac{k}{4k-1} + \dfrac{1}{2}  \}\\
&=& \dfrac{n}{4n-3} + \dfrac{n}{4n-1} - \dfrac{4}{3} - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \{ - \dfrac{1}{4(4k+1)} - \dfrac{1}{4(4k+3)} + \dfrac{1}{2k+2} - \dfrac{1}{4(4k-3)} - \dfrac{1}{4(4k-1)}  \}\\
\end{eqnarray}
3. Takes $n \to +\infty $,  we obtain that
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} S_n &=& \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{4}{3} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \{  \dfrac{1}{4(4k+1)} + \dfrac{1}{4(4k+3)} - \dfrac{1}{2k+2} + \dfrac{1}{4(4k-3)} + \dfrac{1}{4(4k-1)}  \}\\
&=& -\dfrac{5}{6} + \dfrac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \{  \dfrac{1}{4k+1} + \dfrac{1}{4k+3} - \dfrac{2}{k+1} + \dfrac{1}{4k-3} + \dfrac{1}{4k-1}  \}.
\end{eqnarray}
 My question is that "How do I do to get to the last result (i.e. $\dfrac{3}{2} \ln 2$)?"

Thank you very much for your important helps?

Comment: How did you find the equality below?

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&  \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} \left[   \dfrac{1}{4k-3} - \dfrac{1}{4k-2} +  \dfrac{1}{4k-1} - \dfrac{1}{4k}  + \dfrac{1}{2} \left[  \dfrac{1}{2k-1} -\dfrac{1}{2k} \right]      \right] \\
&=& \dfrac{3}{2} \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}  \left[  \dfrac{1}{2k-1} -\dfrac{1}{2k} \right]
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thank you dear Sir. You can see that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (\dfrac{1}{4k-3} - \dfrac{1}{4k-2} + \dfrac{1}{4k-1} - \dfrac{1}{4k}) = 1 -\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{5} - \ldots  = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (\dfrac{1}{2k-1} - \dfrac{1}{2k}) .$$

Comment: You have to be careful about doing this with conditionally convergent series. It won't always work.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes, thank you Sir Fimpellizieri. Are you OK with my explanation? Do you have a hint to my second way (using Euler-Maclaurin summation formula )?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. Seems like a really involved way to calculate the sum.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Oh, yes, thank you so much, dear Sir Fimpellizieri!